# Sending base64 array to a nodejs server from react client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, base64, resize

I am trying to send an array of resized base64 images to my nodejs server.

```
if (files) {
  let array: string[] = []
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      files[i],
      700,
      700,
      'auto',
      100,
      0,
      (uri: any) => {
        array.push(uri)
      },
      'base64'
    )
  }
  setImagesToSent(array)
  console.log('Console logging the array:', array)

  dispatch(productImageUpload({ id, array }))
}
```

When I console.log the array, I get the info like so:

```
 Console logging the array: 
[]
0: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAArw
1: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAArw
2: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAaE
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But when I check the network tab I see an empty array..

```
id: "60d57c21acedc20574f2dd2d", array: []
array: []
id: "60d57c21acedc20574f2dd2d"
```

Also when I check my server console, I am not getting anything inside the array,
if I try to send single base64 string it works and the server receive it.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with base64 or resizing. It's a string array with some data in it. What are `productImageUpload` and `setImagesToSent`?

Comment: setImagesToSent is setting local state I didn't use it anyway so it can be ignored. The productImageUpload is the action that I dispatch to redux

Answer (score 0):

If `Resizer.imageFileResizer()` is a promise you have to `await` the function before sending array to server.